# Lenovo Yoga 15 maximum RAM allowed

Tags: memory, thinkpad

My company was provided with a Lenovo Yoga 15, the one including the RealSense F200 camera

It has come equipped with a RAM of 8GB and that's fine. We were thinking to extend it to 16GB according to [this technical specification](http://news.lenovo.com/images/20034/Lenovo%20ThinkPad%20YOGA%2012%2014%2015%20Spec%20Sheet.pdf) . But today for the same model we found a [contrasting one](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/yoga-series/yoga-15/#tab-tech_specs), always from Lenovo website

We tried to contact without success both their support service and their forum so we are forced to ask here too. We saw there are two RAM slots on this laptop so our question is very simple:

Can we buy from the shop two RAM sticks like [this](http://www3.lenovo.com/au/en/accessories/memory/notebook-memory-thinkpad-and-lenovo-3000/MEMORY-BO-8GB-PC3-12800-DDR3L-SODIMM/p/0B47381) and extend our RAM to 16GB or not? what's the maximum RAM really supported from this model, 8GB or 16GB?

Comment: Surely you should contact Lenovo and get the answer from the manufacturer? I know of some older Toshiba laptops that have 64 bit architectures (and thus running Windows 7 x64) but can only take a maximum 4GB RAM (anything more and the machine doesn't boot - we tried, against already knowing this fact, just to prove it couldn't be done lol. So I think it would be better directed to the manufacturer, surely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upgrade your ram if you really have two RAM slots and the same RAM sticks.

The maximum of RAM which you can theoretically have is `2^64` Byte (~16 Exabyte). This number is for a 64-bit OS. For 32-bit `2^32` Byte (4 GB) is the limit. Since you have used 8 GB already (and hopyfully could adress the whole 8 GB), you should have 64-bit.

In practice, however, windows reduces the maximum amount of RAM for 64-bit.
To bring some examples:

> Windows 7 Home Premium: 16 GB
>
> Windows 7 Ultimate: 192 GB
>
> see here: [Memory Limits for Windows and Windows Server Releases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

In Linux it's a bit different. For more Information you might read this [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/142070/448613) which is from [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Another limit to your RAM is your motherboard, but since in your *technical specification* there is a maximum of 16 GB the mainboard shouldn't be a problem.

To get assurance you might download a tool like [CPU-Z](http://cpuid.com/cpuz.php), which gives you information of your hardware. Seach for the mainboard and post it here or [google it for maximum RAM](https://www.google.com/search?q=maximum%20ram%2064%20bit&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=n1kXVvmQB8mqywO_sK_oCA#q=maximum%20ram%20%3Cmainboard%20name%3E).

Comment: The ram sticks don't necessarily need to be identical. With many thinkpads one ram stick is under the keyboard (and not meant to be changed easily) and another one's in an easy to access bay under the system. The difference may be due to 'add on' ram vs 'go crazy and max out all the ram' vs "we only have 4gb sticks on hand" options.

Comment: Yes but he talked about buying the same RAM stick again which is definitively possible. And with 2 slots there is no way to achieve 16gb ram is there? Don't think that there are 12 gb ram sticks :-D

Comment: 4+8. Its possible a 8gb config has 4+4, in which case he'd need to take out both sticks of ram.

Comment: But he wants to have 16 GB, not 12. And this is not possible with 2 Sticks if one is 4 GB.

Comment: thanks for the help to everybody, really, but it seems we are losing the main question: if we buy two 8GB ram sticks like the ones linked [provided that 16 GB is the maximum RAM, anyway our need is having on board the maximum value] and we put them on this laptop will it work or not? the question is about the maximum RAM for this specific model, not all the possible configurations available. I tried to contact their customer service in the past days at least in three ways and I don't want to add nothing more otherwise I will say very bad things. Thanks a lot again for the many answers given

Comment: It will work as i explained in the first sentence :-)

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 thank you very much for your clear direct answer to my simple question!

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 I accepted the answer for the time you spent in helping me but if I can give you a suggestion please edit your answer outlining these two features: 1) more importance to the specific laptop model [beyond Windows limit which is a nice to know] 2) both the links posted are technical specifications and one says the maximum limit is 8GB, the other 16GB so when you say "in your technical specification there is a maximum of 16 GB" it's a only part of the truth, because the one asserting 8GB is a technical specification as well and even more detailed than the other. Ciao!

Comment: I can confirm from practice that 16GB are really supported... hope it can help somebody else!